# Python/Pandas - Fill Empty Column Header with row beneath

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very messy dataset/dataframe:

| Column A | Column B |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Column C |

I need to fill all blank column headers with the value from the cell in the row underneath. There are many columns that this applies to so I would need to avoid naming specific columns if possible. I have tried ffill and bfill but i'm struggling to get it to work. Is there a way to specify which row to take the values from?

Desired Output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Column C |

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

I have tried the following with no success:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace missing values from columns by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by first row of DataFrame:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().fillna(df.iloc[0])
```